# Single word for a selfish vote

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes an individual voting in a selfish way.

An example of this is if someone says "I voted because the policy would help *me*, I know it wouldn't work for the wider community." They've voted selfishly, but is there a better word?

Comment: Votes are supposed to be selfish. When they aren't selfish, we say the election was rigged or the voters were coerced or bought.

Comment: +1 @PhilSweet. One (and probably the right) way of looking at it is, the wider community is formed by adding up many "me"s specifically in this context.

Comment: @PhilSweet I don't think that there is any necessity that votes be selfish; they need to be entirely in the gift of the voter, but that voter should certainly be allowed for a policy that hurts them in deference to a understanding of the public good. Indeed I suspect that a working democracy requires both types.

Comment: The term "selfish voting" is actually quite common in scientific papers: https://scholar.google.co.il/scholar?q=%22selfish+voting%22&btnG=&hl=iw&as_sdt=0%2C5

Answer (score 17):

I don't think that there is a single word for this.

I would be inclined to call it a "self-interested vote" rather than a "selfish vote". Example sentence: "65% of voters reported voting in their own self-interest in the recent election".

I prefer "self-interested" as it has slightly less of a value judgement than "selfish" - though if you want to convey the negative value judgement, "selfish" may be the better word.

This is a political point rather than one about language, but there is an argument that if everyone votes in their self-interest then the overall result will then reflect the general welfare. Certainly, if no-one votes in their own self-interest, it's not clear that the result will be in anyone's interest.

Comment: Yeah, and it's often been observed that many segments of the population tend to vote against their own self-interest, mostly for non-altruistic reasons.

Comment: @HotLicks Sounds like somebody's been reading Bryan Caplan.

Comment: Re: "there is an argument that if everyone votes in their self-interest then the overall result will then reflect the general welfare": That's not necessarily true. For example, consider a policy that slightly benefits 60% of the population but massively harms the other 40%: if everyone votes in their self-interest, the result will be a net harm. Or consider a policy with small short-term benefits and massive longer-term costs: depending on the timescales involved, many voters' self-interest might genuinely lie in sacrificing the future for the present.

Comment: " if everyone votes in their self-interest then the overall result will then reflect the general welfare" The overall result would be what the majority would consider to be their "welfare". Look no further than a vote to decide if gay marriages should be legalized.

Answer (score 11):

I think you can call it an ***[opportunistic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/opportunistic)*** vote:

> - Taking advantage of opportunities as they arise.
> - exploiting opportunities with little regard to principle or consequences  - *a politician considered opportunistic*

(M-W)

Answer (score 3):

Consider [**self-serving**](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=self-serving) (AHD):

> Serving one's own interests, especially without concern for the needs
>   or interests of others.

Example:

> This botched free-for-all was an aborted attempt to create new Senate
>   districts, and the outcome wasn't good for Lake County, thanks in part
>   to a blatantly **self-serving vote** by Sen. Alan Hays, R-Umatilla, whose
>   hometown would have been a tiny ink spot in a much larger district if
>   the House proposal had passed. *[(Orlando Sentinel)](http://www.orlandosentinel.com/news/lake/os-lk-lauren-ritchie-senate-congressional-districts-20151111-column.html)*

Answer (score 2):

To justify it from a philosophical perspective consider:

> **Ethical egoism** is the normative ethical position that moral agents ought to do what is in their own self-interest. [...]
>   — [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethical_egoism)

Egoism is one (of many) branches of Individualism:

> **Individualism** is the moral stance, political philosophy, ideology, or social outlook that emphasizes the moral worth of the individual. **Individualists** promote the exercise of one's goals and desires and so value independence and self-reliance **and advocate that interests of the individual should achieve precedence over the state or a social group**, while opposing external interference upon one's own interests by society or institutions such as the government. Individualism is often defined in contrast to totalitarianism, collectivism and more corporate social forms
>   — [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Individualism)

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are looking for a single word, how about **parochial** -- narrowly restricted in scope or outlook. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/parochial

Synonyms include provincial, narrow, insular, limited, restricted, petty, narrow-minded, inward-looking, and small-minded.